# How are maven plugin goals mapped to maven phases?

Tags: java, maven

I am working on maven project recently but really i do not understand how it works internally as coming from ant background.

Here are basic questions which i tried to google but could not get satisfaction.

1)When i run mvn clean install or mvn clean package. Does install or package goal internally run all plugin one by one defined in pom and parent pom 
or to run a plugin we need to execute mvn

2)Does all goal of a plugin gets executed ?

3)How goal , phase and task are related to each other?. Consider the below example

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.companyname.projectgroup</groupId>
   <artifactId>project</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <profiles>
      <profile>
      <id>test</id>
      <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <phase>test</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>run</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                  <tasks>
                     <echo>Using env.test.properties</echo>
                     <copy file="src/main/resources/env.test.properties" tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/env.properties"/>
                  </tasks>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
      </build>
      </profile>
   </profiles>
</project>
```

say if i run mvn test -Ptest, does it mean i am going to run phase test under profile test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large part of that is illustrated in [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

Package goals can either be run explicitly as `mvn release:perform` (calls `perform` goal of `maven-release-plugin`) or they can be *bound to* certain *phase*. Maven plugins often come with some goals pre-bound. You can define your own binding in your `pom.xml` or even specify several different bindings using profiles. In your example, you bind `maven-antrun-plugin:run` to phase `test` if and only if profile `test` is executed.